# jshint - how to fix my if statement

Tags: javascript, jshint

This code works fine...though it may be difficult to read.  However I want to conform to jshint.com, and perhaps make it more readable.

There are so many different ways to change this I don't know the best way?

Basically I need to be able to turn client_validatin on/off.  And if data validates than I make the ajax call to the server.

This felt like a hack when I wrote it, particularly the use of client_fail (i.e. used to determine if the client passed validation.

**For this code**

```
function interface_signin()
  {
  var form_name='signin',
      form_elements=document.forms[form_name].elements,
      response_div='signin_response',
      client_fail=0;
  if(arc.client_validation===1)
    {
    (client_fail=1)&&check_empty(form_elements,response_div,messages.empty)&&check_item(patterns.email,form_elements[0],response_div,messages.email)&&check_item(patterns.pass,form_elements[1],response_div,messages.validate)&&(client_fail=0);
    }
    if(client_fail===0){ajax('arche_model.php',serialize(form_name)+'&a=signin',ajax_signin,response_div);}
  }
```

**I get Errors**

```
Line 466: (client_fail=1)&&check_empty(form_elements,response_div,messages.empty)&&check_item(patterns.email,form_elements[0],response_div,messages.email)&&check_item(patterns.pass,form_elements[1],response_div,messages.validate)&&(client_fail=0);
```

**Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression.**

Comment: I'm no longer convinced these questions belong here, but rather on codereview.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is about how I’d clean it up:

```
function interface_signin() {
    var form_elements = document.forms.signin.elements,
        response_div  = 'signin_response',
        client_fail   = false;

    if(arc.client_validation === 1) {
        client_fail = check_empty(form_elements, response_div, messages.empty) &&
                      check_item(patterns.email, form_elements[0], response_div, messages.email) &&
                      check_item(patterns.pass, form_elements[1], response_div, messages.validate);
    }

    if(!client_fail) {
        ajax('arche_model.php', serialize(form_name) + '&a=signin', ajax_signin, response_div);
    }
}
```

Comment: @stack.user.0: Oh, and I just edited it now - `if(client_fail)` should have been `if(!client_fail)`.

Comment: i think the logic is off though..what if I turn off validation?...just need to flip two variables...and to clean it up a bit more..I'll change the variable name to client_pass... and initialize it to true....if validation fails...set it to false....

Answer (score 0):

Your first and last conditions are assignments:

```
(client_fail = 1)
... && (client_fail = 0)
```

Again, `boss:true` switch.

Please use more whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

To make it more readable, I'd change the operative line to:

```
client_fail = !(
       check_empty(form_elements, response_div, messages.empty)
    && check_item(patterns.email, form_elements[0], response_div, messages.email)
    && check_item(patterns.pass, form_elements[1], response_div, messages.validate));
```

instead of setting flags and unsetting them on success.
and instead of checking `client_fail === 0` just check `!client_fail`.